# (Sub)command synonyms for optparse-applicative

Tags: haskell, optparse-applicative

I would like to add synonyms for the subcommands in my Haskell command line tool. For example `summarise` and `summarize` should yield the same result. Of course I could just add an entirely separate command `summarize`, that appears as an own element in the output of `--help`. But maybe there is a more elegant way.

Here is a self-contained example in a stack script `opt_ex.hs`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
-- stack --resolver lts-18.17 script --package optparse-applicative

import Options.Applicative
import Data.Semigroup ((<>))

data Options = CmdGreet GreetArgs | CmdGroot GreetArgs

newtype GreetArgs = GreetArgs String

main :: IO ()
main = do
    cmdOpts <- customExecParser (prefs showHelpOnEmpty) (info optParser fullDesc)
    runCmd cmdOpts

optParser :: Parser Options
optParser = subparser (
    command "greet" (info (CmdGreet <$> sample) (progDesc "Print greeting 1")) <>
    command "groot" (info (CmdGroot <$> sample) (progDesc "Print greeting 2"))
    )

runCmd :: Options -> IO ()
runCmd o = case o of
    CmdGreet opts -> greet opts
    CmdGroot opts -> groot opts

greet :: GreetArgs -> IO ()
greet (GreetArgs h) = putStrLn $ "Hello, " ++ h ++ "!"

groot :: GreetArgs -> IO ()
groot (GreetArgs h) = putStrLn $ "Howdy, " ++ h ++ "!"

sample :: Parser GreetArgs
sample = GreetArgs <$> strArgument ( metavar "TARGET" )
```

You can run this with `./opt_ex.hs greet John` to get `Hello, John!` and with `./opt_ex.hs groot John` to get `Howdy, John!`. Running `./opt_ex.hs` will give you the following overview:

```
Usage: opt_ex.hs COMMAND

Available commands:
  greet                    Print greeting 1
  groot                    Print greeting 2
```

What would be the most elegant way, to add a command `gruut` in this example, which behaves exactly like `greet`, but produces the least amount of overhead, both in the code and for the user?

Ideally I would like `./opt_ex.hs` to yield something like this:

```
Usage: opt_ex.hs COMMAND

Available commands:
  greet|gruut              Print greeting 1
  groot                    Print greeting 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do this. It works fine for options, because the definition of OptField contains a list of OptName, and adds to that list when you use `(<>)`. But the definition of CommandFields, the thing returned by `command`, is

```
data CommandFields a = CommandFields
  { cmdCommands :: [(String, ParserInfo a)]
  , cmdGroup :: Maybe String }
```

Each String name is thus associated with a different ParserInfo. Of course, you can define a variable containing any ParserInfo you like, and reuse it across two commands, so you won't have to repeat the ParserInfo. But as far as optparse-applicative is concerned, those two commands are distinct, so it will list them separately in the help text. For your example, this would look like

```
optParser = let greeting1 = info (CmdGreet <$> sample) (progDesc "Print greeting 1")
            in subparser $
               command "greet" greeting1 <>
               command "gruut" greeting1 <>
               command "groot" (info (CmdGroot <$> sample) (progDesc "Print greeting 2"))
```

and indeed, when run we see both commands listed:

```
Usage: optparse COMMAND

Available commands:
  greet                    Print greeting 1
  gruut                    Print greeting 1
  groot                    Print greeting 2
```

Comment: Alright - thanks for the confirmation. I guess I will have to live with this workaround.